# Json desconfigura quando faço requisição via http do angular

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, json

Estou fazendo um complemento para Firefox e esse é alimentado por json que vem de uma requisição ajax, que faço via método get de http.

Quando imprimo o json chamando o endereço direto na tela, ele apresenta normalmente, mas quando faço a requisição dele pelo angular ele acusa que o json esta com erro de sintaxe.

Segue os scripts

> Arquivo que esta gerando o Json

Eu mudei um pouco o script, mas agora acusa que o que estou recebendo não é um objeto

como ficou a classe :

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json');

class ListaDeLinks{
    public $links = array();
    function  __construct(){ }
    function addLink($nome,$link){
        $this->links[$nome] = $link;
    }
}

$l = new ListaDeLinks();
$l->addLink('google','http://www.google.com');
$l->addLink('bing','http://www.bing.com');
$l->addLink('yahoo','http://www.yahoo.net');

$rest = json_encode($l);

echo $rest;

?>
```

> Arquivo que recebe o Json

```
var lilink = angular.module('lilinkApp',[]);
lilink.controller('lilinkController',lilinkController);
lilinkController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];

function lilinkController($scope,$http){
    $scope.lilink = "lilink";
    $http.get('http://localhost/webS/lkrest.php')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.links  = data;
    },function(errData){
        console.log(errData);
    });
}
```

> Apresentação

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="pt-BR" ng-app="lilinkApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LiLink</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/lilink.css">
    <script src="../js/lilink.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main ng-controller="lilinkController" class="container-fluid">

        <nav class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="row">
            <section style="background-color:#afa" id="links" class="col-sm-8" >
                {{links}}
            </section>
            <section style="background-color:#faa" id="notificacoes" class="col-sm-4">
                {{lilink}}
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Print da tela de apresentação
[image: Print da tela de apresentação]

Comment: tente assim $http.get('http://localhost/webS/lkrest.php').then(function(dados) {  $scope.links = dados})

Comment: Olá, Emanuel! Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Poderia postar um exemplo do JSON de saída?

Comment: {"links":{"google":"http:\/\/www.google.com","bing":"http:\/\/www.bing.com","yahoo":"http:\/\/www.yahoo.net"}}

Comment: O erro que aparece no print parece não condizer com o código JavaScript. Tem certeza que não está fazendo `$http.get({ method: "POST" ... })` ou algo parecido? Isso também pode ser cache de uma versão antiga do script. Aliás, talvez cache seja a causa de vários erros estranhos que você teve até agora e o motivo de parecer que às vezes algo não funciona, quando está correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já que o retorno é

```
{"links":{"google":"http:\/\/www.google.com","bing":"http:\/\/www.bing.com","yah‌​oo":"http:\/\/www.yahoo.net"}
}
```

no retorno da função do $http.get, que é data, você pega as informações através do `data.links`

```
function lilinkController($scope,$http){
    $scope.lilink = "lilink";
    $http.get('http://localhost/webS/lkrest.php')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.links  = data.links;
    },function(errData){
        console.log(errData);
    });
}
```